# elan1200:00 04f3:3090 touchpad

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, synaptics

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on ASUS ROG GL503VD
my touchpad not working correctly
It works fine in windows but in Ubuntu, it just disconnects and pops up at anywhere on the screen and yes external mouse working fine

after xinput -list 
i found out my touchpad model : elan1200:00 04f3:3090 touchpad

and  I am new to Linux so please help in detail 
thanks for the help

Comment: can you show `journalctl | grep i2c-hid` Maybe this(https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1778087) knowing bug.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to kernel version 5.2 helped me too, but the touchpad dies after suspend.
This is my solution:

Create file in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`with this content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 
if [ "${1}" = "post" ]; then
    modprobe -r i2c_hid
    modprobe i2c_hid
fi
```

And dont forget `chmod +x`.

Comment: On kernel 5.0, this did the trick for me, no need to upgrade the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to kernel version 5.2 finally did the trick for me

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2-rc7/linux-headers-5.2.0-050200rc7_5.2.0-050200rc7.201906300430_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2-rc7/linux-headers-5.2.0-050200rc7-generic_5.2.0-050200rc7.201906300430_amd64.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2-rc7/linux-image-unsigned-5.2.0-050200rc7-generic_5.2.0-050200rc7.201906300430_amd64.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2-rc7/linux-modules-5.2.0-050200rc7-generic_5.2.0-050200rc7.201906300430_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```